# restore with s3cmd file from Glacier - ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd, amazon-glacier, object-storage

Info about my bucket and the object

```
s3cmd info s3://$BUCKET/
s3://$BUCKET/ (bucket):
   Location:  eu-central-1
   Payer:     BucketOwner
   Expiration Rule: all objects in this bucket will expire in '
   policy:    none
   cors:      none
   ACL:       76b81345345erfrefge473b9c6ac3c7238ceab39fddef698645c5076a41: FULL_CONTROL

s3cmd info s3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE
s3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE (object):
   File size: 21927
   Last mod:  Tue, 21 Jun 2016 08:41:03 GMT
   MIME type: binary/octet-stream
   Storage:   GLACIER
   MD5 sum:   f55ff37a27b83c96b8a492d3d3dbb904
   SSE:       none
   policy:    none
   cors:      none
   ACL:       76b81e6138c136e4c7e42d75773sferwf4345egrb39fddef698645c5076a41: FULL_CONTROL
   x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs: uid:503/gname:staff/uname:john/gid:20/mode:33261/mtime:1311191701/atime:1466282917/md5:f55ff37a27b83c96b8a492d3d3dbb904/ctime:1436192978
   x-amz-meta-s3tools-gpgenc: gpg
```

Restore from Glacier:

```
> s3cmd restore s3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE
restore: 's3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE'
```

And finally download the object to my Desktop

```
> s3cmd get s3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE /Users/john/Desktop/                                                      
download: 's3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE' -> '/Users/john/Desktop/$FILE’  [1 of 1]
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden)
```

I receive 403. I use the same credentials for download like for upload two months ago.

Comment: Did you wait at least 4 hours between `restore` and `get`?  If not, `403 Forbidden` would be the expected response, with `InvalidObjectState`.  What's the rest of the error?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Glacier FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/)

> Data Retrievals
>
> Q: How can I retrieve data from the service?
>
> You can download data directly from the service using the service’s
>   REST API. When you make a request to retrieve data from Glacier, you
>   initiate a retrieval job. Once the retrieval job completes, your data
>   will be available to download for 24 hours. Retrieval jobs typically
>   complete within 3-5 hours.
>
> Q: What operations initiate jobs and why?
>
> To retrieve an archive or a vault inventory, you first initiate a job
>   (Click here for more information about vault inventories). Once you
>   initiate a job, you can call the DescribeJob API to monitor its
>   progress. You can also have notifications automatically sent to you
>   once a job completes. Jobs will typically complete in 3-5 hours. Once
>   a job completes successfully, you can download the data requested or
>   access it using Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2).
>
> Q: How long does it take for jobs to complete?
>
> Most jobs will take between 3 to 5 hours to complete.

Today the restore was successful

```
s3cmd get s3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE /Users/john/Desktop/
download: 's3://$BUCKET/$DIR/$FILE' -> '/Users/john/Desktop/$FILE  [1 of 1]
 21927 of 21927   100% in    0s    24.66 kB/s  done
```

The file was not encrypted on my Desktop. I used    `-e, --encrypt         Encrypt files before uploading to S3` option for uploading to S3/Glacier.

There are [APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/job-operations.html) for monitoring retrievals.

> Job Operations
>
> The following are the job operations available in Amazon Glacier.
>
> Topics
>
> ```
> Describe Job (GET JobID)
> Get Job Output (GET output)
> Initiate Job (POST jobs)
> List Jobs (GET jobs)
> ```